# How to find the IP of a device connected through Ethernet Sharing

Tags: ssh, ethernet, network, ping

I often share my MacBook Pro's Ethernet connection with devices like a Raspberry Pi to log in via SSH and configure files  without using a screen, keyboard, etc.

My current method to find the IP is to ping the hostname. Example: Ping raspberrypi.local.

Recently, I have ran into problems where the hostname is unknown of the device, and I need to login, finding it's IP.

So, I try the command-line utility [fing](https://www.fingbox.com/download), which scans for devcies on your local network, but I had no luck finding the device. Fing seemed to only show devices that were on my wireless network.

Are there any suggestions to find local IP addresses of devices I plug into my Ethernet jack?

Comment: There are a lot of possible applications. Have you tired with: [IP Scanner](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ip-scanner/id404167149?mt=12). With this you can even choose the interface to scan. I guess is way you are interesting in.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. A terminal solution with no additional software would be nice too.

Comment: In that case, here is what you are looking: [link1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406792/list-all-mac-addresses-and-their-associated-ip-addresses-in-my-local-network-la), [link2](http://superuser.com/questions/124453/how-can-i-scan-the-local-network-for-connected-devices-mac-os). You can use `arp`.